# center vertically image bigger than div

Tags: html, css

This question is coming back often but even looking at some solutions, I can't get mine ...
http://jsfiddle.net/6v6cc7y5/2/
I make a slideshow (wordpress) showing en image in a div.
I want the image to be 400px large, 
and vertically centered even if it is higher, I want it 200px max-height.
I call the image from a PHP while for 5 last articles and it makes impossible to use a css background-image.

Here are some solutions I found but couldn't use : (add http://)
http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/Cu3G5/
http:// codepen.io/anon/pen/dHvLc (<- remove added space)

Thanks a lot if you can help me !!!

stackoverflow wants some code to post ... here is a part of CSS

```
.jDiaporama li img{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top: 50%;
    -ms-transform:     translate(0%, -50%); 
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    transform:         translate(0%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Why not set the background image in the while loop using the style attribute?

`<div class="content" style="background-image:".$imagefile.";"></div>`

And then style .content as required

Comment: thanks a lot !!! I missed to include some CSS informations. It works now in the PHP loop.